# Getting error while running sudo commands, from /etc/sudo.conf file

Tags: 18.04, permissions, sudo, gnome-terminal, plugins

I want to run commands in terminal with `sudo` and get in this error for running `sudo` commands:

```
sudo su

sudo: error in /etc/sudo.conf, line 16 while loading plugin "sudoers_audit"
sudo: unable to find symbol "sudoers_audit" in /usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so
sudo: fatal error, unable to load plugins
```

when I check `/etc/sudo.conf` file, it has these plugins :

```
Plugin sudoers_policy sudoers.so
Plugin sudoers_io sudoers.so
Plugin sudoers_audit sudoers.so
```

and by checking `ldd` dependencies for `/usr/lib/sudo/sudoers.so` all of dependencies are exist.

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007f84e17000)
libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x0000007f84d44000)
libaudit.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libaudit.so.1 (0x0000007f84d0d000)
libpam.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpam.so.0 (0x0000007f84cf0000)
libsudo_util.so.0 => /usr/lib/sudo/libsudo_util.so.0 (0x0000007f84cce000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f84b75000)
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007f84deb000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007f84b60000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007f84b34000)
libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x0000007f84b1f000)
```

also, all `libaudit.so.1` dependencies are exist:

```
linux-vdso.so.1 (0x0000007f85188000)
libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 => /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgtk3-nocsd.so.0 (0x0000007f850e0000)
libcap-ng.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcap-ng.so.0 (0x0000007f850cb000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x0000007f84f72000)
/lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 (0x0000007f8515c000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x0000007f84f5d000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x0000007f84f31000)
```

How could I resolve this problem?

Comment: Did you mixed repositories (e.g. different Ubuntu distribution, or even worth Debian repository) ? Can you try to reinstall sudo with `apt --reinstall install sudo` ?

Comment: @ob2 I did not mixed different repositories. for reinstalling sudo I should run this command as 'sudo' ? otherwise how I could install it without sudo ?

Comment: To fix your system, you should boot to a live cd and use chroot or aler grub option to drop in root shell.

Comment: Please add the output of `sudo --version` [Did you try](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/75#issuecomment-739148890) to have  /usr/local/bin ahead of /usr/bin on PATH?

Comment: @ob2 , thanks. I have installed Ubuntu on Jetson nano card & I could not load this card via live CD or flash disk. Also I have not access to grub .

Comment: When i understand right this plugin comes with sudo --version 1.9.1 https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.9.2/sudo.conf.man.html

Answer (score 0):

This is a situation where you need to use a live system image, use the same installation media.you need root privileges to fix this which you cannot access because Ubuntu by default locks the root user.

boot into the live image since Root has no password in live session,
then you need to do few steps
when you open the terminal type 'su' to run session using root user

1- `mkdir /mnt` create a directory then mount your root partition `mount /dev/sdaX /mnt`

2- `chroot /mnt` change the current root, this will let you install stuff in the system not in the live session.

3- `apt --reinstall install sudo` reinstall sudo

4- `passwd -i root` you can try activating the root user by configuring a password for it, this way the root user will be activated when you login next time. (acitvated only for CLI not GUI so press ctrl+alt+f* to login)

5-to enable the root user in the GUI , add the `AllowRoot=true` line in the [security] directive in file `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` file.
and Add the # to comment the following line
`auth required pam_succeed_if.so user !=root quiet_success`
in /etc/gdm3/custom.conf file.

5- then `umount` and restart, when you login you can use root user and password

**Edit:**

if not possible to boot with live image , try the suggested solution for this issue in [here](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/issues/75)

Comment: A lot of wrong things is suggested. There is no need to `mkdir /mnt`, why enable root user, etc?

Comment: The whole sudo purpose is to give root privilege to normal user, and since he has problem running it if. he enables the root user and fix the problem. That’s what I would do

Comment: Giving a user root privileges and enabling root login are different things. And why reinstall sudo then ;-)

Comment: Giving a user root privileges and enabling root login are different things. << first this is clear and I didn’t say they are the same , he needs root which is admin account to do anything that requires installation and reinstallation of packages. 
And why reinstall sudo then ;-) << reinstalling sudo is not necessary at this point but this might fix the original problem with broken packages so he doesn’t need to login with root user.